# HomeKit - Delete Accessory from Room

Tags: ios, homekit

I am creating an app using HomeKit. I am able to add and assign an accessory to the room. how you can eliminate one accessory from the room?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read the documentation, I have never used HomeKit but it looks like you use the home object to add and remove them.

[HomeKit Framework Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/HomeKit/Reference/HMHome_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/HMHome/removeAccessory:completionHandler:)

Answer (score 0):

You would call removeAccesory on the home something like

```
    home.removeAccessory(accessory:lightbulb, completion: {})
```